# How can I get rid of input border in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

In Chrome, my design has a light border or outline along the edges of the search input field. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: check their answer, i just wanted to add "border:0px none;"

Comment: None of the current solutions seem to be working. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I find the highlight extremely useful. I wouldn't use a site that had found a way to disable it. Couldn't find where I was typing. Not everyone uses a mouse to navigate the Internet.

Comment: It also looks like your CSS is broken. The website isn't rendering correctly for me in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, my CSS was broken. Fixed it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
form#search input[type="search"] { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
}
```

Mind that this will disable the select element arrow.

Comment: Well, since you use the minus sign, you have to escape your search term in quotes: `"-webkit-appearance"`

Answer (score 29):

If you mean the blue "glow", add this CSS:

```
outline: none;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
input, select {
    outline: none;
}
```

This will disable the browser outline for all regular form elements.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, it is easy to remove outline. Just set `none` to input field's `outline` property in css.

For e.g.

```
form input[type=text]:focus, form input[type=password]:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Above will remove outline border in chrome and safari browsers on form element focus.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet worked for me:

```
input:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```