# How to reset default styling of input[type="text"]:focus in Chrome and Safari?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I had created a search feature on this [codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/KxAfF/) and seemed fine on Firefox.

[image]

As you can see the state is currently `:focus` and the `input[type="reset"]` was made by adding a background image.

**HTML**

```
<input type="reset" value="">
```

**CSS**

```
.lab-search-field input[type="reset"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url('http://bones-bruxzir.jgallardo.me/assets/img/template/sprite-global.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.lab-search-field input[type="reset"] { 
  background-position: -70px -280px; }
.lab-search-field input[type="reset"]:hover { 
  background-position: -110px -280px; }
```

But in Chrome and Safari the input type reset does not seem to be necessary because there is a button that gets displayed to cleat the input.

**Chrome**

[image: display in chrome]

**Safari**

[image: display in safari]

As you can see, Chrome also adds a border to my `input[type="search"]` and Safari rounds out the input.

I thought that my CSS class of `border: none` would take care of it but apparently only in Firefox.

```
.lab-search-field input[type="search"] {
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 36px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 240px;
  border:none;
}
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

I did find [How can I get rid of input border in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919562/how-can-i-get-rid-of-input-border-in-chrome) and added `outline: none;` which got rid of the blue border in Chrome but not the "X".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the reset button feature of webkit using:

```
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

This works in Chrome for sure, but I haven't had the chance to test in Safari.

Comment: yes it is perfect for chrome, thank you. but is it proper to do `.lab-search-field input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {` if I am only targeting serch in that `<div>` ? because just `::-webkit-search-cancel-button { -webkit-appearance: none; }` will remove it across the entire site. At this point "it works" but not sure if that was how it is intended to be.

Comment: Yes, you can nest your code that way of course. Either:

`.lab-search-field input[type="search"]::webkit-search-cancel-button`

or `.lab-search-field ::webkit-search-cancel-button`. I'm not sure, one or the other should be fine.

Comment: Ok the former works, and also got rid of the cancel button in Safari.

Comment: Yes, Safari is built with WebKit engine as well, so vendor based selectors should work in both of those browsers.