# Get rid of borders of an element when right/left clicked on it

Tags: html, css

I have an `input` of `type="submit"` and I want exist no blue border around this element when I clicked (right or left click) on it.

I added the picture of ***OK mode*** and ***not OK mode*** in chrome browser below:

OK mode picture is similar to:

[image]

And Not OK mode picture is similar to:

[image]

I should say this problem exist in Firefox browser too but the style of that extra borders is dotted.

I tried many ways to solve this problem using `CSS` like:

Setting `border:none;` or `border-width:0;` in default mode and `:hover` mode and `:focus` mode of the `input` but it doesn't fix and still remained.

Also I read some articles about it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919562/how-can-i-get-rid-of-input-border-in-chrome) but it doesn't work yet and not working for me.

Any advanced help will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set 
`outline: none;`

```css
input[type="submit"]{
  background: #0075E9;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #FFD400;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Go to the next step"/>
```